# Replace Character inside brackets

Tags: android, string, replace

Hi to all coders out there. Let me do this straight.

I want to replace all character in a string inside a opening and closing brackets.

what I have in my code.

```
string value= str.replaceAll("\\[.*\\]", "strToReplace");
```

It's working , but the problem is it also delete the brackets.

ex:

```
 I want to say [Hello].
```

the result:

```
 I want to say .
```

How can I achieve that? Anyone? Thanks in Advance. It will be a really big help in me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = str.replaceAll("\[.*\]", "strToReplace")
```

to

```
String s = str.replaceAll("\[.*?\\]", "["+"strToReplace"+"]")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string= str.replaceAll("\[.*\]", "strToReplace")
```

to

```
String s = str.replaceAll("\\[(.*?)\\]","[" + "strToReplace" + "]");
```

Comment: @JayR Ok bro,enjoy coding.